# Java socket issue while getting the public certificate

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a Java client which sends the request to CA (certificate Agent) server on SSL socket. Server is in c++ and communication will be on TLS protocol.

Once I send the request on socket through client, server respond with `Not Authorized` and provides a trusted certificate to client. Now I have kept the trusted certificate which contains ( RSA private key + certificate) into Java keystore and again trying to send the request to server, but still not recognizing the request and again falling to `Not authorized`.

What not able to understand I am missing. Do I need to pass some extra parameter with client socket request to server so that I can be identifiable.  and once it is authorized? I need the public certificate of server which I can store into keystore.

Comment: can you provide the relevant code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Keystore require server certificate + server key , use following command to generate keystore

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.pkcs12 -in bserver_cert.pem -inkey bserver_pk.pem

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Also note that whether your certificate entry is present in cacerts file or not, cacerts located in your jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts by using following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/cacerts  > java_cacerts.txt
```

Take a look at java_cacerts.txt. See if it includes the same certificate that is present in the browser by searching for a matching serial number.

If it is not present, then this could be the reason for the error, and we can fix this by adding the certificate found in the browser.
Back in the browser, export the Root CA. Choose the "X.509 Certificate (DER)" type, so the exported file has a der extension.

Assuming the file is called example.der, pick the alias 'example' for this certificate. Next import the file.

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore  /path/to/cacerts -file example.der
```

Also check whether you set environment variable like this

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/sachin/softwares/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/security/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustAnchors=/home/sachin/softwares/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

May this will helpful for you !!!

Comment: Actually i got this "abc.pem" from client where it contains the RSA private key and Certificate.

Comment: i am using there 2 command for export and import in cacaert file:  openssl pkcs12 -export -out ipo_certnew.pkcs12 -in abc.pem
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\certificate\certnew.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -deststoretype JKS

Comment: Refer http://acs.lbl.gov/~boverhof/openssl_certs.html#Using%20these%20certificate/key%20pairs%20with%20nettest link for generation of pem & cert file.

Comment: I have done the import successfully in keystore. Still it is not working. Just wanted to know whether i need to do some code change as well in .java file related to certificate keys and data ( i don't think, but may be). also map the environment set for java keystore : System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
            System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

Comment: change your trustStore property value to keystore.jks file as like  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",info.keystorePath+"keystore.jks");